# vba　型が一致しない

Tags: vba

ExcelのVBAで特定の文字の最終行と最初の行を探す方法で、file.xlsmのデータから範囲してtbl_data.xlsファイルにデータを貼り付けるVBAですが、このコードだと型が一致しないとエラーが表示されます。

どのように修正すればいいでしょうか。

```
Sub try()
 Dim r As range
 Dim rr As range
 Dim aju As range
 Dim ajuu As range
 Dim aku As range
 Dim akuu As range

 Set r = Columns("D").Find("T140420001", After:=range("D" & Rows.Count))
 Set rr = Columns("D").Find("T140420001", After:=r, SearchDirection:=2)
 Set aju = Columns("AJ").Find("Upper13", After:=range("AJ" & Rows.Count))
 Set ajuu = Columns("AJ").Find("Upper13", After:=aju, SearchDirection:=2)
 Set aku = Columns("AK").Find("Lower13", After:=range("AK" & Rows.Count))
 Set akuu = Columns("AK").Find("Lower13", After:=aku, SearchDirection:=2)

 range(r, rr).Select
 range(aju, ajuu).Select
 range(aku, akuu).Select

    Windows("file.xlsm").Activate
    range("AD7:AE16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Workbooks("tbl_data.xls").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    range(Cells(r.Row, aju.Column), Cells(rr.Row, akuu.Column)).Select '変更範囲
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Windows("file.xlsm").Activate

 End Sub
```

Comment: コードをステップ実行して、どの行のどの変数がエラーになっているのか切り分けると、解決につながると思います。(参考: https://www.tipsfound.com/vba/01010)

Comment: Workbooks("tbl_data.xls").ActivateをDim akuu As range
の後に追加したらうまくいきました。

Comment: @user25636 さん、お疲れ様でした。回答の横のチェックマークを押すことで回答を承認できますので、よろしければお願いいたします。上のコメントを追加の情報としてよろずやさんの回答にコメントすることもできます :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

回答ありがとうございます

検索して見つからなかった場合の処理はどのように記述すればいいのでしょうか、
     If r Is Nothing Then '検索失敗

```
    MsgBox "検索対象は見つかりませんでした。"

Else    '検索成功

    MsgBox "T14042は" & r.Row & "行目の" & _
    r.Column & "列目です。"

End If
```

このように記述しても型が一致しないとエラーが表示されます。

Comment: こちらの内容は回答ではなく、よろずやさんの回答へコメントする形で投稿するか、新しい質問として投稿すべき内容かと思います。一度削除して再投稿して頂けませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

＞どのように修正すればいいでしょうか。
最初に検索対象のブックをアクティブにすればよろしいかと。
あと、検索して見つからなかった場合の処理が抜けてますよ。